# Footer in pdf with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a footer in every page of a PDF document. I want to have a name and the current date. I'm using this code, but it's only printing in the last page. I need it in every page. What am I missing here?

```
DateTime horario = DateTime.MinValue;
document.Add(new iText.Paragraph(document.BottomMargin, "TEST FOOTER" + horario));
```

Comment: Please show a bit more of your code.

Comment: If you're using iText7, have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/3259

Comment: And if you're using iText5, this should contain some hints:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-html-headers-and-footers-page

Comment: I'm using iTextSharper 4.1.6 ,i will look this articles.

Comment: I tried a lot of things,but dont seen to work,i need something simple,its just a simple footer with a date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manage to fix doing this.
In my class that create the pdf i add this line.

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = new PDFFooter();
```

and i created another class called PDFFooter.

```
 public class PDFFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        // write on top of document
        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnOpenDocument(writer, document);
            PdfPTable tabFot = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1F });
            tabFot.SpacingAfter = 10F;
            PdfPCell cell;
            tabFot.TotalWidth = 300F;
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
            cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            tabFot.AddCell(cell);
            tabFot.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
        }

        // write on start of each page
        public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
        }

        // write on end of each page
        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            DateTime horario = DateTime.Now;
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
            PdfPTable tabFot = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1F });
            PdfPCell cell;
            tabFot.TotalWidth = 300F;
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TEST"+" - " + horario));
            cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            tabFot.AddCell(cell);
            tabFot.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Bottom, writer.DirectContent);
        }

        //write on close of document
        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the header part of this, why is the header text located at the back of my DGV headers? How do we place the DGV down a bit?